Shell script repeating command for 1 argument (of 3) 3 times
I'm using a shell script in a gitlab ci pipeline to update .env variables depending on the branch's context. Overall it is working as expected, except that 1 of the 3 variables is being repeated 3 times.
here is the call from the pipeline:
- chmod +x manage_back_env.sh
    - source manage_back_env.sh "$MONGO_DB_URI" "$MONGO_DB_NAME" "$APP_HOST"

here is the script:
#!/bin/sh

update_env() {
    local key="$1"
    local value="$2"
    local env_file="$3"

    sed -i "s|^$key=.*|$key=$value|g" "$env_file"
}

update_env "MONGO_DB_URI" "$MONGO_DB_URI" "config.env"
update_env "MONGO_DB_NAME" "$MONGO_DB_NAME" "config.env"
update_env "APP_HOST" "$APP_HOST" "config.env"

(i've tried this without the function, making it very basic, and updating the file 1 variable at a time, but this creates the same result).
The .env file has values in place for local development-
MONGO_DB_URI: "value for the URI"
MONGO_DB_NAME: "nameOfTheSpecificDB"
APP_HOST: "hostName@host.com"

when the following script gets run in the gitlab ci pipeline, I end up with :
MONGO_DB_URI: "new value for the URI"MONGO_DB_URI: "new value for the URI"MONGO_DB_URI: "new value for the URI"
MONGO_DB_NAME: "newNameOfTheDB"
APP_HOST: "newHostName@host.com"

I only have the most basic understanding of working with scripts like these, but cannot find any clear direction online, and cannot figure out why only the 1 value is repeated 3 times but the others come through as expected. I define the variables at the start of the job stage and have verified (multiple times) that the config.env file on the repo only has the MONGO_DB_URI variable written once.
Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks
UPDATE
I added some logging and I think the issue is stemming from the '=' in the mongo uri string. When logging the current value for the key I get:
Current value of MONGO_DB_URI in config.env: "mongodb+srv://user:password@dbname.y9ss0vl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites

where it cuts off and in the inital string there is a '=' (MONGO_DB_URI="mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster.0jkjn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"). However, I also noticed that where the URI value is being repeated happens at the same spot, but with each repeat there is a longer portion of the uri string.

Are key-value pairs separated by = or : ?

As an aside, the |g flag is superfluous when your regex can only match once per line.

Do your files have DOS line endings where they shouldn't, or are you perhaps running this on some godforsaken platform where they are required, but missing? See also Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?

Did you make sure, that your environment variables don't contain characters which have special meaning to sed? In particular, you didn't show us the value of MONGO_DB_URI. Look out for hidden characters, i.e. display it with printenv MONGO_DB_URI | od -cx

@oguzismail the pairs are separated by = in the config.env file.@triplee I'm running this on gitlab's ci, have not come accross any mention of line endings. below is an adjusted version of the MONGO_DB_URI MONGO_DB_URI="mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster.0jkjn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority". All variables are strings but i'll look to see if theres something there with sed. Thanks

So I did not get a clear answer as to why the issue was occurring. I adjusted the code a few times, removed the g command in case that was affecting it, but no matter what I continued to get the repetition of the MONGO_DB_URI variable. In order to move forward, I switched to a bash script with awk instead of the shell script with sed and this has worked as expected:
#!/bin/bash


update_env() {
    local key="$1"
    local value="$2"
    local env_file="$3"
     
    #set logging of values I'm passing and what is already in file
    echo "Updating $key=\"$value\" in $env_file"

    current_value=$(grep "^$key=" "$env_file" | cut -d '=' -f 2)
    echo "Current value of $key in $env_file: \"$current_value\""

    awk -v key="$key" -v value="$value" -F '=' '
        BEGIN { OFS=FS }
        $1 == key { $2 = "\"" value "\"" }
        { print }
    ' "$env_file" > "$env_file.tmp" && mv "$env_file.tmp" "$env_file"
}

update_env "MONGO_DB_URI" "$MONGO_DB_URI" "config.env"
update_env "MONGO_DB_NAME" "$MONGO_DB_NAME" "config.env"
update_env "APP_HOST" "$APP_HOST" "config.env"

